# Div with two syled components

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I am pretty new to styled components, and I am trying to convert a site with vanilla css to styled components. My issue is that I have a div with with multiple classes, but I don't know how do to render my Gatsby frontend using styled components

For example the following snippet:

```
<div className="section-center hero-center">
        
</div>
```

I started by creating two styled components files like so:

```
import styled from "styled-components"
export const SectionCenter = styled.div`
      width: 90vw;
      margin: 0 auto;
      max-width: 1170px;
    `
```

and the second component:

```
import styled from "styled-components"
export const HeroCenter = styled.div`
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
`
```

In my Hero.js component I do my import statements

```
import React from "react"
import * as styled from '../styled'

const Hero = () => {
  return (
    <styled. SectionCenter>
  <styled.HeroCenter>

// content goes here

</styled.HeroCenter>
            </styled.SectionCenter >
            )
}

export default Hero
```

This is what I have so far, but it's not the way the original div was, with one div having two styles. Is there another way to accomplish that? To have two styles on one div similar to vanilla css?

Answer (score 1):

Styles can be extended. So if heroCenter is a custom version of SectionCenter, you can do something like:

```
import styled from "styled-components"
export const SectionCenter = styled.div`
      width: 90vw;
      margin: 0 auto;
      max-width: 1170px;
`
export const HeroCenter = styled(SectionCenter)`
  width: 100vw;
`
```

Then Hero.js can use just the HeroCenter component. More details in [official docs](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#extending-styles).

Comment: sorry, I have to edit my request as I forgot to paste in the correct code, but my request is still the same, if you have two styles on the same div in vanilla css and then convert it to styled components